# Complex analysis with $f(z)=\cot z$. Holomorphicity and residues

Tags: complex-analysis

> 1. What are the points of discontinuity of $f(z)=\cot z$
> 2. What is the domain of holomorphicity?
> 3. What are the residues?
> 4. Can I find the number of zeros - number of poles using Cauchy formula?

**My thoughts:**

Rewrite $\cot z=\cos z / \sin z$.

1) It's discontinuous at the zeros of $\sin z$, at $z=k\pi$ for $k\in Z$

2) Here I see that there is no $\bar z$ dependance, so it's holomorphic where it's defined on $\{z \in \mathbb C |z\ne k\pi \}$

3) How do I compute the residue? There is an infinite amount of them? Each at $z=k\pi$

4) I know the argument principle $\oint \frac {f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=2\pi i (N_0-N_\infty)$. E.G. Can I find the number of poles of $\cot (z)$ on some domain, using this formula?

Is there something interesting I could do with $\cot$ and the argument principle?

Answer (score 1):

The function is holomorphic at each point where $\sin z\ne0$, because a quotient of holomorphic function in a neighborhood of that point.

For the residue at $k\pi$, just consider that $\cot(z+k\pi)=\cot z$, so the residue is the same as the residue at $0$; since
$$
\lim_{z\to0}z\frac{\cos z}{\sin z}=1
$$
the residue is $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what about the arguemnt  principle application, is this possible?

Comment: If so, could you give me an example to try?

Comment: @GRS You know all poles and the residue at each of them; what else?

Comment: I dont know, I was trying to cook up a problem to solve

Comment: In principle, if $\Gamma$ is a simple closed positively oriented contour enclosing a region $R$, you can  write (number of zeros in $R$) - (number of poles in $R$) as the integral of $2\pi i f'(z)/f(z)$ around $\Gamma$, but actually computing the integral will be harder than simply counting the zeros and poles.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The function $f'(z)/f(z)$ has the “antiderivative” $\log\cot z$. This might help, but the zeros and the poles are surely easier to compute.